# Post Apocalyptic Novel with Dangerous Motorcycles, Gangs, Games, Spies. Late '80s/early '90s

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, soft-sci-fi

This one has always stuck with me but I've never been able to find it, perhaps due to the noise when looking for post-apocalyptic motorcycle novels...

The main protagonist was trained as some sort of spy or agent that could repeat physical movements perfectly over and over again and sometimes used it to win repeatedly at one-arm bandits. (I know, not too realistic)

The setting was either post-apocalyptic or something similar. Many people rode around on dangerous motorcycles with various parts removed/added. I think the motorcycle types had special names. The most important point was that there were several 'games' going on. I don't remember what the purpose of these games were, but I know one game was groups of women taking polaroids of those they had slept with, and then, I believe, the evidence would be used for nefarious purposes. The protagonist (a male) gets caught up in this very situation unexpectedly.

I remember getting this book from a school library in the 91/92 timeframe and thinking that the book was quite new - so that's why I gave it the late '80s, very early '90s timeframe.

I used to think that the title had the number of games in it, or contained the word 'Super,' but I can't tell if that is good information or not at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going by the Wikipedia article, this may have a few elements in common with [The Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_(Yurick_novel)). Before following that link, note I'm adding trigger warnings for horrific sexual violence in the book, mentioned several times in Wikipedia's description.